# Vue.js cannot read the property of a json object brought from STRAPI

Tags: image, api, vue.js, undefined, strapi

I'm using VUE.JS and I want to display an image of a json object brought in from an API built with STRAPI but it throws the following error.

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined".

En la plantilla vue, he probado con

```
<v-card v-bind:img-src="menu.image[0].url"
    v-bind:title="menu.name"
    style="max-width:20rem">
```

and with:

```
<v-card v-bind:img-src="menu.image.url"
    v-bind:title="menu.name"
    style="max-width:20rem">
```

in both it gives the same error

This is the json:

```
[
{
    "_id": "60035145339db62a385ba032",
    "name": "Buffalo Wings",
    "quantity": "15 piezas",
    "price": "26000",
    "description": "Trozos de alitas de pollo apanadas,",
    "time": "15 minutos",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-16T20:49:09.235Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-16T21:15:33.095Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "image": {
        "_id": "60035762339db62a385ba038",
        "name": "buffalo-wings-2-800x600.jpg",
        "hash": "buffalo_wings_2_800x600_dd299e2810",
        "ext": ".jpg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "size": 78.55,
        "width": 800,
        "height": 600,
        "url": "/uploads/buffalo_wings_2_800x600_dd299e2810.jpg",
        "provider": "local",
        "related": [
            "60035145339db62a385ba032"
        ],
        "id": "60035762339db62a385ba038"
    },
    "id": "60035145339db62a385ba032"
}
```

]

This is the script

```
   await fetch("http://localhost:1337/menus").then(
    (res) => res.json()
    ).then((data) => {
      this.menus = data;
    });

  console.log(this.menus);
```

Comment: _"it throws the following error"_... what is the error (you didn't include it in your question)?

Comment: It should just be `menu.image.url`.  No `[0]`, it's not an array.

Comment: I have tried and it gives the same error

Comment: True Phil, forget to show the error:

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined".